# Neo4j+Popoto.js: Node size adjustment

Tags: neo4j

I use the Popoto.js to visualize the data stored in Neo4j. I am trying to show the nodes as pictures and icons as exampled in [here](http://www.popotojs.com/examples.html). Some of nodes in my graph have to many sub-nodes. The size of the nodes appear so big and overcome to each other which cause a bad appearance on visualization. I checked the `app-template.js` and `popoto-min.js` file to change the size of nodes but couldn't find how to change it.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of IMAGE type nodes can be customized with "getImageWidth" and "getImageHeight" functions in configuration.

The default value is 125px for both as defined in [DEFAULT_PROVIDER](http://www.popotojs.com/documentation/provider.html#DEFAULT_PROVIDER)

You can change the size by customizing these functions in 
**popoto.provider.nodeProviders** like the example below:

```
"getImageWidth": function (node) {
    return 50;
},

"getImageHeight": function (node) {
    return 50;
},
```

Note that you can also change the link distance between nodes in graph with the [LINK_DISTANCE](http://www.popotojs.com/documentation/graph.html#LINK_DISTANCE) property in configuration:

```
popoto.graph.LINK_DISTANCE = 150;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked well.